# Is every totally geodesic surface minimal?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $S$ be a hypersurface (codimension $1$). If $S$ is completely geodesic, does that imply that it is minimal? If not, what are the conditions? If yes, is there a stronger result (e.g. the normal curvature is zero)?

The converse is clearly false (think of any nontrivial minimal surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$).

What happens for general submanifolds?

A reference would also be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if $S$ is any totally geodesic submanifold of a Riemannian manifold, then $S$ is a minimal submanifold. This holds true in all codimensions, not just for hypersurfaces. (Note that the terms ***minimal submanifold***, ***minimal hypersurface***, and ***minimal surface*** all mean submanifolds that are *critical points* for the area functional, not necessarily ones that are area-minimizing.)

A totally geodesic submanifold is one for which the (vector-valued) second fundamental form is identically zero, while a minimal submanifold is one for which the mean curvature vector is everywhere zero. Since the mean curvature vector is the trace of the vector-valued second fundamental form, the result follows.